# TCPDF Tamil Unicode Issue

Tags: php, unicode, tcpdf

My code is

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;//chrome
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/freeserif.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$pdf->setFont($font_family='freeserif',$font_variant='',$font_size=10);

$pdf->AddPage();

$utf8text = '
<html><head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>
<p>தமிழ் தமிழ் குதிரை </p>
</body></html>';

$pdf->writeHTML($utf8text, true, 0, true, true);

$pdf->Output('example_008.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

but Tamil letters குதிரை not properly showing now.

[image]

TAMIL UNICODE CHARACTERS IN PDF CORRECTLY

Comment: TCPDF [does not support Tamil](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/609).

Comment: any other option available to render pdf tamil